# How to Handle form Data in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider A from with inputs of numbers and Radio Booleans yes or No.
For Yes we add 2 inputs and for NO we substract. I am using React JS with Bootstrap.
1st Component is form with inputs. Then on clicking Submit Button another Component is called with Table (2*2) Giving answer and another text output. 2nd Component called means that earlier Component gets erased off by document.write(). I have used the following code for instance.

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
class AS extends Component {
  AS(props) {
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  ASSubmit(event) {
    document.write(
      class ASSub extends Component {
        render(){
          return (
            <table className="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
              <thead><tr><td>Particulars</td><td>Amount Rs.</td></tr></thead>    
              <tbody><tr><td>Final Amount</td><td>{"Here first answer"}</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Suggestion: </td><td></td>"Another statement dependent on answer"</tr>
              <tr><td>Final Conclusion</td><td></td></tr>    
              </tbody>    
            </table>
          )
        }
      }
    );
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.ASSubmit}>
            <table className="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead><tr><td>Particulars</td><td>Inputs</td></tr></thead>
                <tbody><tr><td><label for="Amt_Lumpsum">Num1</label></td><td><input type="number" name="Amt_lumpsum" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><label for="Amt_Periodical>Monthly reciepts</label></td><td><input type="number" name="Amt_Periodical" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Whether Amt paid or not</td><td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Yes" /><label for="payment">Yes</label><input type="radio" name="payment"value="No" /><label for="payment">No</label></td></tr>
                        <tr><td></td><td>            
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            <button type="Reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                        </td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
      </form>
      
    );
  }
}
export { AS }
```

This is how UI should Look.
1st : Navbar with form
2nd : Navbar with Result Table (So by using write.document we are not erasing Navbar)

Comment: You can't write react components directly to the Dom, why are you doing this?

Comment: What is the purpose of using `document.write`? BTW, direct DOM manipulation is a react anti-pattern. Was `handleSubmit` omitted for brevity? Where is the code that handles *any* form data and/or logic? Please include all relevant code in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. Also include what the issue is and any debugging details.